# How to scrape the data off multiple tags with same tag name and attributes in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the data from this website:
https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=35.0868&lon=-90.0568

[image]

This image shows the info I wanna extract but I couldn't do it as I couldn't find a way to extract data from same tag name under the same tree...

I have successfully extracted some data before but I couldn't fetch it. Here is my code:

```
def weatherFetch(latitude,longitude):
URL = 'https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?'

URL = URL + 'lat=' + str(latitude) + '&lon=' + str(longitude)
print(URL)
dictionary = {
    'latitude':str(latitude), 'longitude':str(longitude),
    'cityName': '', 'weatherCondition': '', 'temprature': ''
}

res = requests.get(URL)
if res.status_code==200: #we have used legit coordinates
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    arr=soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'panel panel-default'})
    if arr:
        try:
            cityName = arr[0].find("h2","panel-title").text
            weatherCondition = arr[0].find("p", "myforecast-current").text
            temprature = arr[0].find("p", "myforecast-current-lrg").text

            windSpeed = arr[0].find_next("td", "text-right") #this is the line of code where i am supposed to fetch wind speed

            print(windSpeed)


            dictionary['cityName']=cityName
            dictionary['weatherCondition'] = weatherCondition
            dictionary['temprature']=temprature
        except:
            return dictionary
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) - instead of the image, post a minimal example of the markup you are trying to *search*. [mcve]

Comment: The image is not of the code but the output i want....

Comment: You shouldn't post images of data either. You should always try to include the data you are operating on/with.  Looks like you should be *searching* for `<div id="current_conditions_detail" class="pull-left">`.

Answer (score 1):

Find the element with id: `current_conditions_detail`

1. Then find all the `tr` tags inside the table.
2. for each tr tag, find `td` tags, there will be 2 such tags.

First one is the title and the second one is the value

Comment: I am a newbie so can you give some lines of code for better understanding

Answer (score 1):

You could just use pandas to get the table, then filter out the stuff you want using `.loc`.

Not sure what the rest of your code is trying to do. You're creating a dictionary but you only want it to return it if there's an exception??

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

def weatherFetch(latitude,longitude):
    URL = 'https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?'

    URL = URL + 'lat=' + str(latitude) + '&lon=' + str(longitude)
    print(URL)
    dictionary = {
        'latitude':str(latitude), 'longitude':str(longitude),
        'cityName': '', 'weatherCondition': '', 'temprature': ''
    }

    res = requests.get(URL)
    if res.status_code==200: #we have used legit coordinates
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
        arr=soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'panel panel-default'})
        if arr:
            try:
                cityName = arr[0].find("h2","panel-title").text
                weatherCondition = arr[0].find("p", "myforecast-current").text
                temprature = arr[0].find("p", "myforecast-current-lrg").text

                df = pd.read_html(str(arr[0]))[0]
                windSpeed = df.loc[df[0] == 'Wind Speed', 1][1]

                print(windSpeed)

                dictionary['cityName']=cityName
                dictionary['weatherCondition'] = weatherCondition
                dictionary['temprature']=temprature
            except:
                return dictionary

latitude,longitude =  35.0868, -90.0568          
weatherFetch(latitude,longitude)
```

**Output:**

```
https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=35.0868&lon=-90.0568
SW 5 mph
```